# React Native Circular Cutout

Tags: react-native, styling

I am trying to create a circular cutout in React Native, something similar to the image below where the **light grey is transparent**.

[image: cutout]

I can successfully duplicate this design using absolute positioning and fixed background colours but am unsure of how I would go about making the cutout around the image at the top transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a method of doing this using only styling, the trick was to use the inside of a curved border to create the circular cutout.

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@campbellmg/cutout-transparent)

[image]

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 20,
          width: 80,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ width: 40 }} />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: -10,
          left: 70,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          borderBottomWidth: 10,
          borderLeftWidth: 10,
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 45,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          right: 85,
          top: -15,
          borderRadius: 100,
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: -10,
          right: 70,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          borderBottomWidth: 10,
          borderRightWidth: 10,
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderBottomRightRadius: 45,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          height: 20,
          width: 80,
          borderTopRightRadius: 30,
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}
      />
    </View>
    <View
      style={{
        height: 180,
        width: 200,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position:"absolute"` to image view, and set its position accordingly.

Try this,

```
  <View
    style={{
      height:400,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      marginTop: 100,
    }}>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 40,
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 10,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -40,
        zIndex: 1,
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent:"center"
      }}
    >
    <Text>Image</Text></View>
    <View
      style={{
        height: 400,
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        borderRadius: 40,
      }}
    ></View>
  </View>
```

[see working expo example here](https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/profile-like-view)

Comment: Thanks for the input but the issue I am having here is making the the light grey section transparent. See the text under the image

Comment: Transparent in the sense 1. you are not providing any color or 2. there is something in background which should appear around the image in the border.

Comment: if you want to make it transparent, then the border will disappear.

Comment: There will be a image underneath this component that should be visible through the gap

Answer (score 0):

You can create the top left and top right sides of the box then put an image cutout in the middle in the shape of the semicircle for the circle to fit in.

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', width: 125, height: 45, borderTopLeftRadius: 45}}></View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', width: 125, height: 45, borderTopRightRadius: 45}}></View>
    </View>
   <View style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', height: 300, width:308, borderBottomLeftRadius: 45, borderBottomRightRadius: 45}}></View>
   <View style={{position: 'absolute', alignSelf: 'center', top: 145}}>
     <ImageBackground
        style={{width: 60, height: 50}}
        source={{uri: "https://i.imgur.com/ncjPX1k.png"}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'grey',width:50, height: 50, borderRadius: 27.5, top: -30, alignSelf: 'center'}}></View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
 </View>
```

[See the snack (styling is a bit off):](https://snack.expo.io/@pulpdood/cd7352)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't do this... Use two views to get the box (not the circle) The cutout is just a square view, then apply a boarderRadiusBottomLeft and borderRadiusBottomRight as 50 on each. Done.