# How to create navigation like this with CSS/React Native?

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-stylesheet

I would like to create a navigation with CSS/styled components for React Native (so no all styling hacks and attributes will work) that looks simmmiliar to this one that the Google Tasks app uses, see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmEwt.jpg).

What I mean is mostly the floating "+" button, the "cut off" section from the "div" bellow it and having shadow that matches correctly.

I'm really not sure how to accomplish this, especially the cut off section in a div. So, if anyone could point me in a direction then I should be fine. :)

Comment: you can use display:fixed and set icon on middle of div , and set negetive top to this.but i think this approach is ok in android and make bug in ios

Comment: Hmm, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932281/react-native-circular-cutout) possible solution, and it works okayish but is not fully what I'm looking for as shadows to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.